# An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation:The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

Issue in AWS Codepipeline. Previously is was working fine unfortunately facing a above issue. I haven't change anything. Also provided ecr permission to codebuild role. I tried with all the solution.

[Clouwatch Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg1Ak.png)

[Error in Codebuild log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4SVR.png)

[Provided Permission to Codebuild Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYSah.png)

Please give the solution for the same

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).